# How can I convince my company to sponsor corporate cycling gear?

Tags: clothes

I work for a medium sized company (about 200 people). We have a small but reasonably active BUG (Bicycle Users Group). I've seen corporate cycling gear before and have some friends who can get corporate gear cheap.

I'd like to propose to my company that they subsidise some corporate branded cycling gear, but I'm not sure how to pitch it. I've created a short survey on SurveyMonkey and know there is definitely some interest from my colleagues.

From my perspective, the pluses are:

- Employee satisfaction - getting a bit of a perk of the job
- Corporate marketing/promotion - getting the company visible, especially in group rides

What else should I emphasize in my pitch? Has anyone done this successfully and if so, how did you go about it?

Comment: This question cannot have a single answer in its curent form. "Has anyone done this successfully and if so, how did you go about it?" in particular is polling the community.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is centre it around a competition that a contingent of your BUG is competing in.  That way you can pitch around the competition and the exposure.  Even if it is just a big social ride.

Work out your team.  Work out the cost of the corporate uniforms.  Pitch based on the competition demographics (Hopefully it appeals to your company), also on the fact you have internal participants.

You won't have gear available for the whole company but this is the easiest starting point.  Then from there you can prove interest and say it is encouraging employee health.  Not sure where you are located but some companies jump on programs like this.

Good Luck.

Comment: You could bring some other ideas to the table:

 - What clients do you have? If they are local businesses that are not competing against each other commercially then you could sell various spots on a jersey design, solicit bids for each panel or have an auction.

 - Have an event. Get your company (and others) to sponsor the event, selling jerseys to the bicycle group at your company (and others). The event need not be anything more than you plus a few mates doing a local route for charity. In the UK that would be Lands End to John O Groats or a stage of the Tour de France.

Answer (score 0):

There's a definite brand loyalty card to play too - it emphasises both that the company could have some visibility out there in the real world but also that its employees are so happy and proud to work for them that they're prepared to advertise this to fellow road users.

Be prepared to rebutt some possible negatives, though, amongst many non-cyclists cyclists, especially in urban areas, don't always have the best reputation for obeying *all* traffic laws *all* the time. Your employers or senior decision makers might not necessarily want to be associated with riders who jump red lights or buzz pedestrians on road crossings. Perhaps offer to have riders sign a good conduct promise for when they're wearing the shirt. Indeed, that could be a way of getting some local press (if it's a specifically local company) - highlighting being good citizens.